# Is it Possible to create external table with options delimiter?

Tags: greenplum

I want to create external table in greenplum :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hctest.ex_abs
(
a text,
b text,
c text,
d text,
e text,
f text
)
LOCATION ('gpfdist://192.168.56.111:10000/abs31032020.csv')
FORMAT 'CSV' (DELIMITER ',' HEADER);
```

But the value in file abs31032020.csv is like this :

```
Employee ID,Time Type,Start Date,End Date,Number Of Days,Comment
90007507,Leave,05/08/2020,05/08/2020,1,"dear mas Andria, kindly approve 1 day leave at 8th May. Thank you."
90006988,Leave,04/20/2020,04/21/2020,2,"Dear Mas Tommy,
Herewith I would like to ask your approval for my leave which will be taken on 20 - 21 April 2020 (2 days of leave). I take this leave because of I need to attend the family wedding out of town along with visiting my extended family before Ramadhan in my hometown. 

Your approval will be highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Andrian Indrawan"
```

In field Comment, there is a value that use "enter". And it read to be a new row in greenplum table.

So what can i do to create the external table from the format file like this?? Thanks

Comment: CSV is supposed to handle this because the string has double quotes around it.  Try (DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '"' HEADER)

Comment: CSV is not a strong file format. I think you need to preprocess the data by modifying the newline character and join your multiline data back to 1 liner.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this on GP 6.4 and it worked correctly with two changes:

- Used 'file://' instead of gpfdist
- Added a closing double quote on the last line of the data sample provided.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext.ex_abs
(
    a text,
    b text,
    c text,
    d text,
    e text,
    f text
)
LOCATION ('file://mdw/tmp/t.csv')
FORMAT 'CSV' (DELIMITER ',' HEADER);
```

Comment: My bad. I didn't copy the data correctly. So I didn't have to add the extra double quote after copy the whole sample. Still works after grabbing it all.